# Criteria to make a Google Developer Console Account

Tags: android

I have made some Android apps, some I want to sell for free and some paid, I have got to know that there is Developer Console for this, even that there is a $25 fee, so just before joining, I want to know the Criteria, especially age.

EDIT:
Is it okay if I am under 15?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [This](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html) link to know the details about registration and [This](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html). 
And as for the age limit, there isn't one.